# Anime where characters combine with animals/monsters

Tags: story-identification, animated-series

I remember seeming this anime when I was visiting my parents' home country, Bangladesh. The TV would have some shows that were interesting and I later realized were from other countries but dubbed.

One show I still can not figure out what it is. I don't know if it's an anime or cartoon but it was in the style of anime. It had people combining with animal/monster companions. The combinings would lead to a human wearing armor and wielding weapons based on the partner/monster they combined with. Different people fuse with the monsters and get different transformations. I remember the main character having a chibi knight-like monster. They also have a sorta mole/sloth-like monster companion. I tried to remember more detail but this is all I have. I think they said “fusion” to combine and transform, and “separation” to revert to two different beings. Though that just might be the weird dub I listened to.

I certainly hope someone can find out what anime/cartoon I'm talking about. (P.S. I know it's not *Digimon Fusion*. That anime has the different monsters fuse with each other. The anime/cartoon I can recall primarily has people fuse with these monsters.)

Comment: See if this scene rings any bells: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pzSdur2lgnQ

Comment: If it's not Digimon Fusion, is it Digimon Frontier?   The kids there fuse with spirits into monsters.  The spirits aren't (technically) monsters themselves, but...

Comment: Digimon Frontier would have been my guess too; check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AryHwXUenVg

Answer (score -1):

***[Pluster World](https://myanimelist.net/anime/3637/Bouken_Yuuki_Pluster_World)*** (2003-2004)?

> According to the legend, the once peaceful "Pluster World" plunged into chaos and darkness due to the manifestation of the evil MINASUTA. At that time, selected Plusters were combined with humans, and successfully sealed away the evil MINASUTA. It was then believed that the peace which had returned would continue forever. Greenery and trees filled the land, flowers bloomed everywhere, living creatures soar in the blue sky, run on the land, and swim in the seas.
>
> However, this peacefulness was once again lost due to reappearance of the MINASUTA... Now, the fusion of Plusters and Humans once again opens the door for a hot adventure!

I was looking for it too. I think this is the one you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! Are there any extra details you could [edit] in to help motivate why you believe this is what the OP is looking for? Please see [answer] for some helpful information